# Tkinter - inserting information from a text box to a specific location in a python script

Tags: python, tkinter

I've recently finished a data standardisation script and am currently trying to make it more user-friendly by creating an app with Tkinter. I have already managed to run the data standardisation script through Tkinter, but the script requires minor changes between different data sets.

What I'm trying to achieve is inserting a user-defined piece of text to a specific location in the script. I have tried the text widget on Tkinter, however I have only managed to open the script in the app, which is something I avoid doing (optimally the app user would not even need to see the original code).

What I'm rather trying to do is having a Tkinter textbox, with a 'Run' button next to it. That way when a user inserts a specific name (e.g. 'Law Conference Attendees Jan 2020') it would automatically place this piece of text here `df['Data Identifier'] = ''`

My current Tkinter code looks like this:

```
    def __init__(self):
        super(Root, self).__init__()
        self.title("Python Tkinter Dialog Widget")
        self.minsize(320, 200)
        self.text_area = Text()
        self.text_area.grid(column = 2, row = 3)
        self.labelFrame = ttk.LabelFrame(self, text = "Open File")
        self.labelFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 1, padx = 20, pady = 20)

        self.button()
        self.button1()
        self.button2()
        self.textbox()
        self.textbox1()
        self.textbox2()


    def button(self):
        self.button = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame, text = "Browse a File",command = self.open_file)
        self.button.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

    def button1(self):
        self.button1 = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame, text = "Cleanse Campaign Codes",command = self.standardize)
        self.button1.grid(column = 1, row = 7)

    def button2(self):
        self.button2 = ttk.Button(self.labelFrame, text = "Cleanse Data",command = self.helloCallBack)
        self.button2.grid(column = 1, row = 8)


    def textbox(self):
        self.textbox = ttk.Entry(self.labelFrame)
        self.textbox.grid(column = 6, row = 1)

    def textbox1(self):
        self.textbox1 = ttk.Entry(self.labelFrame)
        self.textbox1.grid(column = 6, row = 2)

    def textbox2(self):
        self.textbox2 = ttk.Entry(self.labelFrame)
        self.textbox2.grid(column = 6, row = 3)

    def helloCallBack(self):
        os.system('python data_cleansing_final.py')

    def open_file(self):
        open_return = filedialog.askopenfile(initialdir =  "C:/", title="Select file to open", filetypes=(("python files", "*.py"), ("all files", "*.*")))
        for line in open_return:
            self.text_area.insert(END, line)

    def standardize(self):
        open_return = open_return.apply(lambda x: difflib.get_close_matches(x, textbox)[0])

root = Root()
root.mainloop()
```

I would very much appreciate any help or advice.

Answer (score 0):

You could add a `StringVar` to your textbox.

```
self.inputstring = ttk.StringVar(self.lableFrame, value = 'value')
self.textbox2 = ttk.Entry(self.labelFrame, textvariable = self.inputstring)
self.textbox2.grid(column = 6, row = 3)
```

To read the variable you should use:

```
self.inputstring.get()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make an entry:

`text = Entry(root, width=10)
text.grid(column=0, row=0)`

With a button next to it:

`run = Button(root, text="Run", width=10, command=runClicked)
run.grid(column=1, row=0)`

And then a method called `runClicked` above these:

```
def runClicked():
   userText = text.get()
```

And then the variable `userText` variable will hold whatever the user types in and you can use it as you wish.

All in all your code would look something like:

```
def runClicked():
   userText = text.get()

text = Entry(root, width=10)
text.grid(column=0, row=0)


run = Button(root, text="Run", width=10, command=runClicked)
run.grid(column=1, row=0)
```